# How to work UIImagePicker into view hierarchy when opening to camera

Tags: ios, objective-c

Basically, I want the app to open to the camera immediately, like snapchat. So the AppDelegate directs to the CameraViewController. It opens fine and I can take a picture and it will redirect to a "ConfirmationViewController" of that picture. But if I go to select from the library, it crashes because the "ConfirmationViewController" is being call from the "CameraViewController", which is no longer in the view hierarchy because it called the "LibraryImagePicker".

here is a diagram

```
                             ## AppDelegate ##
                                     |
                          ## CameraViewController ##
                       |                             |
         (photo captured)                (chose from libary button selected)
                  |                                  |
  ## ConfirmImageViewController ##         ## LibraryPickerViewController ##
                                                     |
                                                 (selected image)
                                                      |
                                             ## ConfirmImageViewController ##
```

My code is as follows:

CameraViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

UIView *backgroundScreen = self.view;
backgroundScreen.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWith8BitRed:32 green:32 blue:32 alpha:1];


self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.imagePickerController.view.autoresizingMask = NO;

self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;

self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);

CGRect f = self.view.window.bounds;

UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:f];
self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;

//cosmetic stuff, adding buttons to overlay view

[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
When a photo is captured by pressing the capture button, I call a function that sets up a "ConfirmImageViewController" and then has self.imagePickerController present that view controller.

[self.imagePickerController presentViewController:self.confirmImageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
That works fine. But if I select a photo from the library, it crashes because once the photo is selected in calls the same function above, which has

[self.imagePickerController presentViewController:self.confirmImageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
Here's the code for when I select to choose from my photo library:

- (void)chooseFromLibraryButtonClicked: (id)sender;

{

UIImagePickerController *libraryPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[libraryPicker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
[libraryPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
[libraryPicker setDelegate:self];

[self.imagePickerController presentViewController:libraryPicker animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

When a photo is captured by pressing the capture button, I call a function that sets up a "ConfirmImageViewController" and then has self.imagePickerController present that view controller.

```
imagePickerController presentViewController:self.confirmImageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

That works fine. But if I select a photo from the library, it crashes because once the photo is selected in calls the same function above, which has

```
[self.imagePickerController presentViewController:self.confirmImageViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Here's the code for when I select to choose from my photo library:

```
- (void)chooseFromLibraryButtonClicked: (id)sender;

{

UIImagePickerController *libraryPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[libraryPicker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)];
[libraryPicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
[libraryPicker setDelegate:self];

[self.imagePickerController presentViewController:libraryPicker animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: I do not understand the flow. You present an image picker controller with camera source, user takes a photo, you display some controller, and then you display another image picker from gallery?

Comment: I added a somewhat helpful diagram. But basically when an image is selected (either via capture or library), it calls a function that has [self.imagepickercontroller] present the next view controller. but if i have selected "choose from library", i'm not longer in the imagepickercontroller view controller, I'm now in the library. so when i select a photo and it calls that function i mentioned, it commits an error because self.imagepickercontroller wouldn't be the one presenting the next viewcontroller.